# Replace all columns null value with previous records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to build a query to replace all column's null values with previously available values. By query and dynamic query. Here is what the table looks like.

```
Date       June July August
06/25/2021 200  900  1000
07/09/2021 Null 400  Null
07/14/2021 100  100  600
07/20/2021 500  Null 500
08/02/2021 300  800  400
```

Output looks like

```
Date       June July August
06/25/2021 200  900  1000
07/09/2021 200  400  1000
07/14/2021 100  100  600
07/20/2021 500  100  500
08/02/2021 300  800  400
```

I can do it with one column but I need to replace a lot of columns. Below is the code I wrote

```
select  
    a.Date,
    ISNULL(a.June, x.June) June,
from Temp a
outer apply
(select top 1 June
    from Temp b 
    where b.DATE<a.DATE and 
        b.June is not null and 
        a.June is null order by DATE desc)x
        order by a.date
```

Comment: It is called lag/lead

Answer (score 0):

You can use LAG function to replace previous Non-Null value as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @table TABLE(DateVal DATE, June int, July int, August int)

INSERT @table values
('06/25/2021', 200  ,900  ,1000),
('07/09/2021', Null ,400  ,Null),
('07/14/2021', 100  ,100  ,600 ),
('07/20/2021', 500  ,Null ,500 ),
('08/02/2021', 300  ,800  ,400 );

SELECT dateval, isnull(june,lag(june) over(order by dateval)) as june , isnull(july,lag(july) over(order by dateval)) as  july,
isnull(August,lag(August) over(order by dateval)) as August 
FROM @table
order by dateval
```

| dateval | june | july | August |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-25 | 200 | 900 | 1000 |
| 2021-07-09 | 200 | 400 | 1000 |
| 2021-07-14 | 100 | 100 | 600 |
| 2021-07-20 | 500 | 100 | 500 |
| 2021-08-02 | 300 | 800 | 400 |

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is `lag(ignore nulls)` or `last_value(ignore nulls)`.  But SQL Server does not support the `ignore nulls` option on any window functions.

If you only have one or two in a row, you can use `coalesce()` and `lag()`:

```
SELECT dateval,
       coalesce(june, lag(june) over (order by dateval), lag(june, 2) over (order by dateval)) as june,
       coalesce(july, lag(july) over (order by dateval), lag(july, 2) over (order by dateval)) as july,
       coalesce(august, lag(august) over (order by dateval), lag(august, 2) over (order by dateval)) as august
FROM t
ORDER BY dateval;
```

An alternative approach assigns a grouping for each column based on the number of valid values up to each row.  The value is then spread over all `NULL` values in the group:

```
select t.*,
       max(june) over (partition by june_grp) as imputed_june,
       max(july) over (partition by july_grp) as imputed_july,
       max(august) over (partition by august_grp) as imputed_august
from (select t.*,
             count(june) over (order by dateval) as june_grp,
             count(july) over (order by dateval) as july_grp,
             count(august) over (order by dateval) as august_grp
      from t
     ) t
order by dateval;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ffff435abc08a4e83a8fc67b725bc8b0) is a db<>fiddle.  It also augments the example with more examples of `NULL` values in a row.

Answer (score -1):

The description is a little vague, but as best I understand your request, you want to select cross the columns to fill gaps in the latest values with earlier ones.

In T-Sql this is problably easiest with [Coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
Select Date, 
June, 
Coalesce(July, June) as July, 
Coalesce(August, July, June) as August
From Table
```

Comment: This will replace the row value, not the column value. I want to replace the NULL column value with the previous column value.